# Encoding issue on csv import of Polish characters

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, locale

I have a `fopen()/fgetcsv()` PHP script loading a `UTF8` file with polish characters. I am then saving that string in the mysql database. Sometimes I get broken characters in db and on ouptut, sometimes I get good ones. script being run stays the same.

server LC_ALL and language is `utf8`; (I even explicitly `setlocale` in PHP just in case)
server connection collation is `utf8`;
tables collation is `utf8`;
database collation is `utf8`;
file encoding is `utf8`;
browser opens the page in `utf8`;

What could cause such inconsistent behaviour?
First it imports badly. Then on subsequent run, most of the lines reimport well. On the third and fourth run all the other lines import well, too. But then after a few days, I get bad characters again.

Comment: So you're trying to say the same input can give different output? If no, then please provide an example of the input and corrupt output that is given when the value is retrieved from the db.

Comment: `Karty pamięci` sometimes first produces `Karty pamiÄ™ci`, but on subsequent imports produces `Karty pamięci`. I bet that if I let the file import now again, `Karty pamiÄ™ci` would become `Karty pamięci`. There are other lines in the file, so maybe it comes to certain point and then it starts misbehaving. rest of the file is also Polish strings.

Comment: Also it could be a problem with the terminal itself in the sense it's not correctly representing the data being sent to it by the database because the terminal doesn't have the right character encoding set. Could you try it on a different computer? How exactly are you accessing the database, e.g. phpmyadmin, command line in Windows?

Comment: Output is in browser.. to check the data in db, I use pma.